# Writing string to a file

Tags: rust

```
pub fn write_file(path: &str, content: &str) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .create(true)
        .open(path)
        .and_then(|mut file| {
            file.lock_exclusive().and_then(|()| {
                file.write_all(content.as_bytes())
            });
            Ok(())
        })
}
```

How can I modify this method that it works similarly to `fprintf`:

```
write_file("/output.txt", "hello, {}. look {}", name, box);
```

Comment: Oh, you mean "how can I make my code work like `format!`"? Why not just use `format!`?

Comment: Yes, please. What would be the signature of the method? New to rust, so inspecting `format!` doesn't exactly help me much.

Comment: Easy answer: `write_file("./output.txt", format!("hello, {}. look {}", name box))` Just leverage existing tools. This will mean adjusting your function to take `String` or call `format!(...).as_str()`, either way.

Comment: @tadman *Why not just use `format!?`* - One reason to avoid `format!()` is that it dumps the whole output into a string, which it then writes out in the file and discards. Writing into the file directly, as `write!()` does (and as does C's `fprintf()` referenced by the OP) can avoid the allocation by writing content directly into the file as it is being formatted.

Comment: @user4815162342 I didn't want to go down the macro path, but your answer is great!

Comment: @tadman Thanks. It's somewhat unfortunate that Rust doesn't offer any sort of variadic arguments (at least for multiple-type arguments), but that's how things are. Although beginners are known to abuse macros, there are excellent use cases for them - think logging as one example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to make your function a macro. For example:

```
macro_rules! write_file {
    ($path: expr, $($content: expr),+) => {{
        OpenOptions::new()
            .write(true)
            .create(true)
            .open($path)
            .and_then(|mut file| {
                file.lock_exclusive().and_then(|()| {
                    write!(file, $($content,)*)
                })
            })
    }}
}

//write_file!("/tmp/foo", "hello {}\n", "world")?;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=42f6c2f1f7402cbe3f48083ef1fc70bf)

If you plan to actually use this, be sure to wrap the `File` in a `BufWriter` to avoid multiple tiny writes being sent to the OS:

```
.and_then(|mut file| {
    file.lock_exclusive()?;
    let mut w = BufWriter::new(file);
    write!(w, $($content,)*)?;
    w.flush()   // flush explicitly so write error can propagate
})
```

Comment: Thank you. According to the compiler `w` in your last example needs to be mutable.

Comment: @vasily Thanks, I've now amended the answer.